# Force download with files on other servers

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess

I'm trying to find out how to force a download (right-click + save as) with mp4 files and flv files. I would use .htaccess to force the download, but the mp4 and flv files are NOT on my server. They are parsed direct links from other websites. Anyone know how I can achieve this? I used the download="" html5 tag, but it only seemed to work in google chrome. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The best option here would be to move your "force download" logic from `.htaccess` to a PHP file, and then have that file fetch the remote file and pass it through to the recipient.

Comment: I already have a php file that pulls the remote file from the websites, once they are pulled, they are put in href tags:
<a href="<? echo $mp4link; ?>"></a>

But most browsers just display the video within the browser. I need to prevent this, and make the file download to the users computer.